# Cakephp erro: Class 'mPDF' not found

Tags: cakephp, pdf, mpdf

Instalei o mPDF pelo prompt no github Friends Of Cake, e segui as instruções como no github falava, porém esta dando **erro de classe do mPDF nao encontrada** e erro na linha **$mpdf = new mPDF();**, dando como nenhum arquivo ou diretorio encontrado mesmo havendo o arquivo, não sei como solucionar!

### GerarPdf.ctp

```
    <?php
    include ('/Plugin/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php');
    
        $pagina = 
            "<html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Relatório de lead cadastrado</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>cesar@celke.com.br</li>
                        <li>kelly@celke.com.br</li>
                        <li>atendimento@celke.com.br</li>
                    </ul>
                    <h4>http://www.celke.com.br</h5>
                </body>
            </html>
            ";
    
    $arquivo = "Cadastro.pdf";
    
    
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);
    
    $mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');
    
    // I - Abre no navegador
    // F - Salva o arquivo no servido
    // D - Salva o arquivo no computador do usuário
    ?>
```

### Controller

```
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
    class RelatoriosController extends AppController
    {
    
        public function GerarPdf()
        {
            $this -> pdfConfig = array (
                'orientation' => 'landscape',
                'download' => true
            );
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar meu problema, eu tive que importar o mPDF, entao meu código ficou assim:

```
<?php
namespace Mpdf; //mpf importado
error_reporting(0); //concertando erro de vizualizaçao
ini_set('display_errors', 0);


include ('/Plugin/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php');

    $pagina = 
        "<html>
            <body>
                <h1>Relatório de lead cadastrado</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>cesar@celke.com.br</li>
                    <li>kelly@celke.com.br</li>
                    <li>atendimento@celke.com.br</li>
                </ul>
                <h4>http://www.celke.com.br</h5>
            </body>
        </html>
        ";

$arquivo = "Cadastro.pdf";


$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);

$mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');

// I - Abre no navegador
// F - Salva o arquivo no servido
// D - Salva o arquivo no computador do usuário
?>
```